# Binding an IValueConverter properly

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, ivalueconverter

I am trying to create some sort of label with a glowing background. To achieve this I decided to use a style on a content control. The glow effect comes from two `DropShadowEffects`, which I wish to bind to the `Foreground Property` of the content control. The `Foreground Property` is of type `Brush` and the `DropShadowEffect.Color` is of type `Color`, so I need to convert between those two.

Whenever I try to set the glow color via the converter the glow effect stays black. It seems like the converter code never even gets passed. I did return a pre-defined color (no conversion) in the converter and even added a Debug.Break(), to no avail.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong, or whether there are alternative, possibly better ways to implement a label with a glowing background.

The converter:

```
public class ColorToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null) return null;

        if (value is Color)
        {
            Color color = (Color)value;
            BrushConverter bc = new BrushConverter();
            return bc.ConvertFrom(color);
        }

        Type type = value.GetType();
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Unsupported type ["+type.Name+"]");            
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {

        if (value is Brush)
        {
            Brush brush = (Brush)value;
            BrushConverter bc = new BrushConverter();
            return bc.ConvertTo(brush, typeof(Color));
        }

        Type type = value.GetType();
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Unsupported type ["+type.Name+"]");            
    }
}
```

In a resource dictionary:

```
<local:ColorToBrushConverter x:Key="Color2BrushConverter" />

<Style x:Key="ContentControlGlowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                <Border>
                    <Border.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect
                                BlurRadius="15"
                                Color="{Binding Path=Foreground, Converter={StaticResource Color2BrushConverter}}"
                                ShadowDepth="2"
                                Direction="0"/>

                    </Border.Effect>

                    <TextBlock Name="Highlight" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Margin="10,5,0,0">
                        <TextBlock.Effect>  
                            <DropShadowEffect
                                BlurRadius="15"
                                Color="{Binding Path=Foreground,Converter={StaticResource Color2BrushConverter}}"
                                ShadowDepth="2"
                                Direction="0"/>

                        </TextBlock.Effect>

                    </TextBlock>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and in XAML:

```
<ContentControl Name="cc2" Style="{DynamicResource ContentControlGlowStyle}"
    FontSize="24"
    Foreground="LightBlue"
    Background="LightBlue"
    Content="some content to display"
    FontFamily="Verdana" />
```

Comment: You should take a look at the output window and see if it shows any exception. That could give you more insight as to what is happening.

Comment: VS doesnt complain about the binding in the output window.

Comment: The only other thing that comes to mind is setting a relative source to the color binding.

Comment: @TYY: Setting the RelativeSource to `{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentControl}}`did the trick.  Got some minor additional issues, but those are a different topic and I can handle that. Please write an answer so I can mark it. Thanks.

Comment: No problem glad I could help. I had a similar issue at some point in time and I remember that it had to do with setting the relative source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the problem you are facing you need to set the Relative source to the color binding. The trick to knowing that it is not an issue with your converter is the fact it is never called and VS doesn't spit out any errors meaning that a default has been picked.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your converter seems backwards -- you're converting a `Brush` to `Color`, and you've created a `ColorToBrushConverter` to do so.

Also, I'm not sure why you're redefining the control template in the `ContentControl` style. You should just set a `DropShadowEffect`, that has its `Color` bound to the `ContentControl`'s `Foreground`.

Try this instead:

```
public class BrushToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var solidColorBrush = value as SolidColorBrush;
        if (solidColorBrush == null) return null;

        return solidColorBrush.Color;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and

```
<local:BrushToColorConverter x:Key="BrushToColorConverter" />

<Style x:Key="ContentControlGlowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <Setter Property="Effect">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DropShadowEffect
                        BlurRadius="15"
                        Color="{Binding Foreground,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}, Converter={StaticResource BrushToColorConverter}}"
                        ShadowDepth="2"
                        Direction="0"/>
            </Setter.Value>
       </Setter>
</Style>
```

use it like

```
<ContentControl 
    Foreground="Yellow" 
    Style="{DynamicResource ContentControlGlowStyle}">
    <TextBlock Text="TEST" FontSize="72"/>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: The name of the converter was a bit confusing, yes :) The reason for redefining the control template is, that simply adding a drop shadow effect on a textblock will only add a tiny amount of glow. Surrounding it with a border and adding a dropshadow to that as well will give me the amount I want. TYY already solved the problem with the binding, but +1 as your solution was useful and correct. Thank you.